# Return as pointer, reference or object?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to return a pointer, scalar and reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431484/when-to-return-a-pointer-scalar-and-reference-in-c)

Hi,

In example 1. I don't know what to use. `Sample` should be returned as pointer or reference or like it is. Next, in example 2. `GetSample` is used to retrieve Sample object and pushed on queue. I don't know here if should i use `std::dequeue<Sample*>`. I see that object sample was copied 2 times (when returned from `GetSample` and when was pushed on queue).

How should it be if speed is not so important. I'am interested in best practice.

```
// 1.
Sample GetSample()
{
    Sample sample;
    // fill sample
    return sample;
}

// 2.
class AAA
{
    void MakeSomethingWithSample()
    {
        Sample sample = GetSample();
        samples.push(sample);
    }
    std::dequeue<Sample> samples;
};

class Sample
{
public:
    Sample(void);
    ~Sample(void);

    boost::optional<std::wstring> window_caption_;
    boost::optional<std::wstring> image_fs_name_,
        image_full_path_,
        resource_image_name_;
    boost::optional<boost::posix_time::ptime> probe_time_;
    HWND window_handle_;
};
```

Comment: Please tell us what `Sample` is.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. In your example, you are using a local copy inside `GetSample()` that is copied in `Sample sample = GetSample();` and then you push this into the `samples` queue. By doing `samples.pop()` you retrieve the oldest `Sample` element in the queue. If you want to know if dequeues are better than queues, that much depends on what you want to do with them.