# c++ object instantiated/passed to method as reference or pointer or valueA

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I#ve already looked at a couple of posts here on SO but I still dont quite get it. Here's a little bit of code (note: I wasnt trying to implement a linked list):

```
#include <iostream>

class Node
{

    int data;

public:
    Node(void);
    Node(int data);

    void setData(int data);
    int getData(void);

};

class List
{

    Node theNode;
    Node* theNode2 = NULL;

public:
    List(Node& param, Node* param2);

    void addNode(Node& param);

    void addNode2(Node* param);

    Node* getNode(void);

    Node& getNode2(void);

};

Node::Node(void)
{
    this->setData(20);
};

Node::Node(int data)
{
    this->setData(data);
};

void Node::setData(int data)
{
    this->data = data;
};

int Node::getData(void)
{
    return data;
};

Node* List::getNode(void)
{
    return theNode2;
};

Node& List::getNode2(void)
{
    return theNode;
};

List::List(Node& param, Node* param2)
{
    theNode = param;
    if (param2 != NULL)
    {
        theNode2 = param2;
    }

    std::cout << "theNode Data " << theNode.getData() << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TheNode2 data " << theNode2->getData() << " " << std::endl;
};

void List::addNode(Node& param)
{
    theNode = param;
    std::cout << " TheNode data " << theNode.getData() << " " << std::endl;
};

void List::addNode2(Node* param)
{
    if (param != NULL)
    {
        theNode2 = param;
    }
    std::cout << "TheNode2 data " << theNode2->getData() << " " << std::endl;
};



int main (void)
{

    Node firstNode;
    Node secondNode(300);
    Node* thirdNode = new Node();
    // Node* forthNode = new Node(392);

    Node fifthNode(2001);

    List firstList(firstNode, thirdNode);

    List secondList(secondNode, &fifthNode);

    Node* asu = firstList.getNode();

    std::cout << asu->getData() << std::endl;

    delete thirdNode;
    delete asu;

    Node someNode = firstList.getNode2();

    std::cout << someNode.getData() << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

I get that references are aliases. I understand that for primitive types. But I still dont quite get what's the big difference between references and pointers when it comes to object instantiation, other than:
- pointers can be null
- in case of pointers, I need to call delete at some point

I saw a singleton implementation that returns a pointer to the object. I guess this is the only way in this case because you need teh returned obejct to be on the heap.

But in my example? I compiles, but where do I need to use references really and where to I need to use pointers? What is the difference between returning a reference to and object and returning a pointer to an object?

For linked lists in C++: Could I use references for the next and previous nodes?

And in this post they say that you can also return by value, like in java:

[When to return a pointer, scalar and reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431484/when-to-return-a-pointer-scalar-and-reference-in-c)

So I could add this:

```
Node List::getNode3(void)
{
    return theNode;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Node someOtherNode = firstList.getNode3();

std::cout << someOtherNode.getData() << std::endl;
```

which is return by value, right?

Thanks to anyone who takes a couple of minutes to provie some clarity!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: References are not necessary, they are syntactic sugar that makes it easier to use data without copying it without exposing you to raw pointers and their potential for abuse.  You should use references any time you don't **need** to use pointers but **need** to change the data.  You should use const references any time you only need the value but want to avoid creating a copy (as with pass-by-value).

Comment: okay, so references instead of pointers (except when I need them) and const references instead of pass by value (except when I need it). is that fair to say?